# href attribute of anchor element changed automatically

Tags: javascript, html, tags, anchor

I am trying to access `href` attribute of HTML `<a>` element but somehow that value gets changed automatically.

Following is my code :

```
function getTDElement(anchorString)
{
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  // i think this is not a good way to add child to html element but 
  // i have to do it for some unavoidable reason
  td.innerHTML = anchorString;
  var anchor = td.firstChild;
  // following line prints url like
  // http://localhost/myservlet?myParam=foobar
  console.log(anchor.href);
  return td;
}

// im passing only /myservlet?myParam=foobar in following line
getTDElement("<a href=/myservlet?myParam=foobar>display</a>");
```

I am not able to understand why and how href attribute of  element changes automatically.

Can anyone please shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Where's the `<a>` element? You are overwriting the HTML content with `/myservlet?myParam=foobar`!

Comment: Sorry, i wrote wrong parameter. I have corrected changes in question. Thanks for comment.

Comment: And what does `console.log()` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `href` property on a link element is a special property, not a simple string. It is liable to change your href value to the absolute URL it thinks it resolves to. You can get the unchanged value using `getAttribute`.

```
console.log(anchor.getAttribute('href'));
```